# Error: # ** Fatal: (vsim-3807) Types do not match between component and entity for port "XOUT". when attempting to run a simulation

Tags: vhdl, quartus

I'm new to VHDL, so I don't know what the warnings mean. I am trying to make a simple XOR gate. The code was able to compile, but had 14 warnings and had a fatal error while attempting to run a simulation. I think the issues I am coming across have something to do with [this section in my compilation report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXq9G.jpg) I'm not really sure what it means for an input/output port to be unconstrained or how to make it constrained.

Here is my code:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

ENTITY C1XOR IS
PORT(IN1,IN2:IN BIT;
         XOUT :OUT BIT);
END C1XOR;

ARCHITECTURE below of C1XOR IS
SIGNAL IN1_inverted:BIT;
SIGNAL IN2_inverted:BIT;
SIGNAL AND1OUT:BIT;
SIGNAL AND2OUT:BIT;

COMPONENT and_gate IS
    PORT(X,Y:IN BIT;
             Z:OUT BIT);
END COMPONENT and_gate;

COMPONENT or_gate IS
    PORT(A,B:IN BIT;
             C:OUT BIT);
END COMPONENT or_gate;

COMPONENT invert_gate IS
    PORT(D:IN BIT;
          E:OUT BIT);
END COMPONENT invert_gate;

BEGIN
    G1:invert_gate
        PORT MAP(
            D=>IN1,
            E=>IN1_inverted);

    G2:invert_gate
        PORT MAP(
            D=>IN2,
            E=>IN2_inverted);

    G3:and_gate
        PORT MAP(
            X=>IN1,Y=>IN2_inverted,
            Z=>AND1OUT);

    G4:and_gate
        PORT MAP(
            X=>IN2,Y=>IN1_inverted,
            Z=>AND2OUT);

    G5:or_gate
        PORT MAP(
            A=>AND1OUT, B=>AND2OUT,
            C=>XOUT);
END below;

ENTITY and_gate IS
PORT(X,Y:IN BIT;
         Z:OUT BIT);
END and_gate;

ARCHITECTURE and_arc of and_gate IS
BEGIN
    Z<= X AND Y;
END and_arc;

ENTITY or_gate IS
PORT(A,B:IN BIT;
         C:OUT BIT);
END or_gate;

ARCHITECTURE or_arc of or_gate IS
BEGIN
    C<= A OR B;
END or_arc;

ENTITY invert_gate IS
PORT(D:IN BIT;
      E:OUT BIT);
END invert_gate;

ARCHITECTURE invert_arc of invert_gate IS
BEGIN
    E<= NOT D;
END invert_arc;
```

Edit: Could it be related to this warning: "Critical Warning (332012): Synopsys Design Constraints File file not found: 'C1XOR.sdc'. A Synopsys Design Constraints File is required by the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer to get proper timing constraints. Without it, the Compiler will not properly optimize the design."?

Comment: The Modelsim vsim-3807 says during elaboration the port  type of XOUT on an entity declarations doesn't match the port type of the same name of a component declaration. That problem is not demonstrated in the question's VHDL. Is c1xor instantiated with a declared component somewhere?  The Synopsys issue is unrelated.

Comment: I don't think so. Again I'm pretty new to VHDL. Is there something I need to do to C1XOR aside from declaring it as an entity and listing its ports?

Comment: Your code is fine. It doesn't attempt a simulation, and you don't say what the simulation error was, so you'll need to post your simulation code if you want to get any further. The sdc warnings are unrelated.

Comment: The VHDL shown analyzes, elaborates and simulates. XOUT is a port of mode out on c1xor. The error might show up in an un-seen testbench component instantiation where the port type in the component declaration doesn't match the entity declaration during elaboration. A testbench isn't provided.  The Design Compiler warning is from the lack of a [Synopsys Design Constraint file](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/programmable/quartushelp/17.0/reference/glossary/def_sdc.htm). A testbench isn't synthesized.